# Textbox loses value after postback (ASP - C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been having a tough time with updating my text boxes and could really use some help. So basically, I have a popup panel for the user to select a value that I then populate into a certain text box.

I am certain that the problem is either very simple to solve, or that I'm confused on what post back actually does. Here is a snippit of my code below:

```
    protected void grvSearchRecords_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.Compare(e.CommandName, "EditRow", true) == 0)
        {
            long nMagic2Value = Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument);
            string tmp = GetItem(nMagic2Value, currentTableName);
            textBox1.Text = tmp;
            Debug.WriteLine(textBox1.Text.ToString());
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "SearchRecords", "$(document).ready(function(){ $('#mask, #divSearchRecordsGrid').fadeOut(\"fast\"); });", true);
        }
    }
```

The "tmp" variable grabs the value I need and assigns it to the text box.

I then run a Debug statement and confirm that the value is correctly assigned to the box. As soon as the function ends, however, that assigned value is lost, and the text box never populates with the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just got it working. The textbox I was trying to change was part of a Content tag and nothing else. I enclosed it in an UpdatePanel and added a trigger for my GridView, and now it works!

The joys of learning a new language.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code around a post back check

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
//your code here
}
```

This will ensure that your code does not run when it is a post back, so your textBox will not be clear.

Post back means that the page is not being rendered for the first time, for example a page refresh.

Comment: I put all of my code inside of the if statement you suggested, but now it doesn't fire at all.

Comment: @MoonDawg where is the textbox, in a gridView?

Comment: No, it is in a Content tag. Does it need to be in a GridView?

Comment: no, do you initialize the value of the textbox in page_load or somewhere else? @MoonDawg

Comment: It is initially populated with a value from my local database. This part is inside a (!IsPostBack) if statement in Page_load. Here's the line of code. textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(objDT.Rows[0]["FieldName"]);  Do I need to reassign my new value in Page_load as well as my RowCommand function?